# Get the value of an associative array if the key or part of the key is matched

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I've an `array` Let's say

```
$temp = array('sep', 'oct');
```

and I've an array of months that contains the month name as `key` and number of month as the `value`

```
$monthsArray = array('January' => 01, 'February' => 02, 'March' => 03 //....so on);
```

I want that if `$temp` value matches with (OR contains) the `key` in `$monthsArray` then output it's value

in above case it should `output 09` and `10`

any clue?

Thanks

Comment: you can use array_key_exists() function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$search = array('first' => 1, 'second' => 2, 'third' => 3);
$temp = array('sec', 'th');
for($i=0; $i<count($temp); $i++){
    foreach($search as $key => $value){
        if(strpos($key,$temp[$i])!== FALSE){
            echo $value . ' ';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it returns the `10` and `0` when I ran on the actual array. what can be issue. It should return 09 and 10

Answer (score 2):

You could try a function like this

```
function getMonth($temp){
  global $mothsArray;
  foreach ($monthsArray as $key => $value) {
      foreach($temp as $check)
         if ( strpos($key,$check)!== FALSE) {
             return $value;
         }
  } 
  return false;
}
```

I'm pretty sure you can make it better, but you can start from this

Comment: I did a bit change in the code, it returns the `10` and `0`. what can be issue